# code for Tabview screen gives an error when compiled

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

This code gives an error when compiled, and it looks really simple. It should be a test screen for tabview in app.  Maybe somebody knows what s wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

struct screenone: View {
    var body: some View{
        ZStack {
            Text ("Screen 1")
                . bold()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.mint)
            .clipped()
    }
}

struct screenone_previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View{
        screenone()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change `ContentView()` to `Screenone()` in your `App` struct? If not try replacing your `App` struct with the code below.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Screenone()
        }
    }
}
```

Once that is done replace your `screenone` struct with the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Screenone: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Screen 1")
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.mint)
        .clipped()
    }
}

struct Screenone_Preview: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View {
        Screenone()
    }
}
```

The code above works for me.

In the future please provide the specific error so that it is easier to address your problem!

Answer (score 0):

After your **ZStack{}** ended, you forgot to put a dot **.** before frame. Put the dot and run again. Follow the below code.

```
ZStack {
        Text ("Screen 1")
            . bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) //added dot before .frame
    .background(.mint)
    .clipped()
```

If this does not work, then you should include your error message here because let us assume your error is not the way to help you.

Still, that **.** is surely the error.